# Creating table from json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this table

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="(k, obj) in items | orderBy:'key'">{{obj.key}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That shows a table of only one row with all the items in the json ($scope.items) ordered alphabetically by the key value.

Is there any way to make it so that it has a fixed number of columns, more than one row and keeps being sorted by the key value?

Comment: put the `ng-repeat` on the `<tr>` - then, each `<td>` can contain a property of `items` with separate `<td>`s for each property (for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the parent index and slice up array put a tr every X times

```
<table class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="trs in items" ng-if="$index % howMany == 0" ng-init="pIdx=$index">
     <td ng-repeat="(k, obj) in items.slice(pIdx,pIdx+howMany) | orderBy:'key'">{{obj.key}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this example declare a variable `var howMany = 6` so it will have 6 tds every row.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Even though it sorts the values top-bottom and left-right instead of left-right and top-bottom, like this table in the top: http://jsfiddle.net/4wyaayc0/ . I'll try to understand how you did that to make it look like the table at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Try this fiddle to get yourself started

https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/17932/

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="tstCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="(k, obj) in items | orderBy:'key'">
        <td>{{k}}</td>
        <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
        <td>{{obj.type}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The short answer is yes. You need to change how you are using ng-repeat. It does not repeat the tag it is contained within, only the tags inside the ng-repeat tag.

Answer (score 1):

This will show a fixed number of columns and remain sorted.

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>Other Property</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="(k, obj) in items | orderBy:'key'">
    <td>{{obj.key}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.otherProperty}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `ng-repeat` to the `<tr>` - like:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="(k, obj) in items | orderBy:'key'">
    <td>{{obj.key}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.propertyOne}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.propertyTwo}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this case, you have a three column table (add/remove columns as you wish and change the properties depending on your objects's properties